# Trying to make my leaflet map work on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, css, mapping, cross-browser, leaflet

I have been tearing my hair out of late trying to get my web map working on internet explorer. It's working flawlessly on every other major browser but none of the content will load in IE. Anyone out there who's good at browser testing that could help out?

I know the leaflet javascript api, which I'm using for this project, supports IE in theory. In practice this isn't working out too well...

Let me know if there is anything else I could add that would help in deciphering this problem...

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was caused by a typo that is not even present in the question. Too localized

Comment: does Ie9 supports leaflet.js or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a trailing comma issue... won't be making that mistake again!

Answer (score 0):

IE9's dev tools report that there's an error on line 1875 of *wax.js*, which appears to be [Reqwest](https://github.com/ded/reqwest).

The error is "Operation aborted" when trying to set the `src` of a `<script>` element to `http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/slremap.slremap.jsonp?callback=grid`.  My guess is that since you're on a HTTPS page, IE doesn't like dynamically inserting a script from HTTP.

I'd try:

- Host the page on regular HTTP.
- Use jQuery's AJAX facilities instead of Reqwest.

Comment: I'll try and host it elsewhere to see if it works. Even when I load it locally it doesn't work though...And the tiles shows up but nothing else does.